# Can't 1 rep users troll this meta?

Tags: discussion

Since you can't gain or lose any rep here, nor can get question or answer ban. Can't I just put random text in the title and body and then post? (As question or answer or even comment)

How does meta handle those situations\users?

Comment: You need 5 reputation points to participate in meta: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta And if that doesn't work, there are manual suspensions.

Comment: I am amazed 3 got it in instant and I didn't found anything about it. *going to sharp my search skills*

Comment: The machine that hands out the bans doesn't look at rep, just post scores.  I wouldn't assume too much, maybe it does actually look at meta posts as well :)

Comment: @HansPassant Sounds strange, can you give source?

Comment: @Wooble For example? And what's with the specific number?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If someone was trolling this site (or indeed any child meta) the sequence of actions once it came to the moderators attention would probably be:

1. Leave comments (if appropriate) telling them to stop.
2. Send them a mod message telling them to behave. This would be just a warning as there's no separate suspension for child metas.
3. If they continued, send them another warning but this time make it clear that their main account (and hence meta account) will be suspended if they transgress again.
4. Suspend their account.

Obviously one or more of these steps can be omitted if necessary.

It should go without saying that the posts/comments would be deleted.

Comment: steps 1 through 3 look redundant

Comment: @gnat - you'd be surprised. Even the most persistent of meta trolls can (and have been) stopped by step 3.

Comment: wish step 3 would work for [homework spammers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6844/31260). But I guess these won't stop even after step 4

Answer (score 8):

No, you need 5 points before you can post on Meta.

Quoting from the [*What is Meta* help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta):

> You must have 5 reputation to participate on meta.

Also see the [*Participate In Meta* privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta):

> Awarded At: 5 Reputation

If a user with the privilege becomes disruptive enough, moderators can still give such users a suspension, but it'd apply to both the main site *and* to Meta.

Answer (score 5):

[You need 5 reputation points to be able to post on Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta), so 1 rep users trolling Meta is not an issue.